# Spring MVC blocking queue with initializing of huge library

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I am using a huge library in my application. I cannot initialize the library every time a request come so I put the initialization into the configuration. I have implemented a queue and a service for managing the queue. After application is loaded I have two instances running. Problem is that it stucks and no response is getting back.

**Application context xml:**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.metadata.tripletws.model" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.metadata.tripletws.service" />

<bean id="wsdService" class="com.metadata.tripletws.service.WsdService" init-method="init"></bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.metadata.tripletws.controller" />
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class WsdService
{
  public final static int MAX_THREADS = 2;
  private WsdQueue queue;

  public void init()
  {
    try {
      queue = new WsdQueue(MAX_THREADS);
      queue.initQueue();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(WsdService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }

  public WSD getInstance() throws InterruptedException
  {
    return queue.dequeue();
  }

  public void releaseInstance(WSD instance) throws InterruptedException
  {
    queue.enqueue(instance);
  }
}
```

**Queue**

```
public class WsdQueue
{
  private List<WSD> queue = new LinkedList();
  private int limit = 5;

  public WsdQueue()
  {
  }

  public WsdQueue(int limit)
  {
    this.limit = limit;
  }

  public void initQueue() throws InterruptedException
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
      System.out.println("Initializing WSD nr." + i);
      WSD wsd = new WSD();
      wsd.Initialize();
      this.enqueue(wsd);
    }
  }

  public synchronized void enqueue(WSD item) throws InterruptedException
  {
    while (this.queue.size() == this.limit) {
      wait();
    }
    if (this.queue.size() == 0) {
      notifyAll();
    }
    System.out.println("Adding instance");
    this.queue.add(item);
  }

  public synchronized WSD dequeue() throws InterruptedException
  {
    while (this.queue.size() == 0) {
      wait();
    }
    if (this.queue.size() == this.limit) {
      notifyAll();
    }
    System.out.println("Taking instance");
    return this.queue.remove(0);
  }
}
```

and here is the controller

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class ApiController
{
  @Autowired
  private WsdService wsdService;


  @RequestMapping(value = "/wordnet", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public @ResponseBody
  ArrayList<LexicalWord> getWordsFromSentence(@RequestBody String sentence)
  {
    ArrayList<LexicalWord> results = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
      WSD wsdInstance = wsdService.getInstance();
      List<CWSDResult> list = wsdInstance.AnanlyseSentenceToList(sentence);
      for (CWSDResult res : list) {
        if (!res.hasLegalSense) {
          continue;
        }

        String key = getHighestProbableSynsetKey(res);
        if (key != null && res.senses.containsKey(key)) {
          Synset synset = res.senses.get(key);
          if (synset != null) {
            results.add(new LexicalWord(res.token, synset.getLexFileName()));
          }
        }
      }

      wsdService.releaseInstance(wsdInstance);

    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(ApiController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return results;
  }

}
```

This is the first time I am making a queue and working with threads and I appriciate any kind of help or example. There is no error, it just stucks, does nothing and no response is send back.

**EDIT1:**

after answers I changed the code, but no luck. Still stucks. Maybe the problem is somewhere else, but when I send a single request it works and I get the response.

```
@Component
public class WsdService
{

  public final static int MAX_THREADS = 2;
  private BlockingQueue<WSD> queue;

  public WsdService()
  {
    queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(MAX_THREADS);
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init()
  {
    try {
      for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        WSD wsd = new WSD();
        wsd.Initialize();
        System.out.println("WSD nr. " + i + " initialized!");
        queue.put(wsd);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(WsdService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }

  public WSD getInstance() throws InterruptedException
  {
    return queue.take();
  }

  public void releaseInstance(WSD instance) throws InterruptedException
  {
    queue.put(instance);
  }
}
```

and here is new applicationContext

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.metadata.tripletws.model" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.metadata.tripletws.service" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.metadata.tripletws.controller" />
```

**SOLUTION**

So ..after lot of digging of the library I assumed it is not possible to use multithreading there. Anyway I used the blockingQueue in other service (NLP) and it is working nicely (Same as EDIT1 just the variable is different). Thanks everybody for your help.

Thanks,

Michal

Comment: You have 2 instances, either remove the xml declaration for the bean and put `@PostConstruct` on the `init` method or remove `@Service` from the implementation. That way you will have a single instance. Do you really need multiple instances of WSD? If it is thread-safe you can just use a single instance...

Comment: Unfortunetly it is not thread safe.

Comment: I edited code and used `@Component` + `@PostConstruct`. When I remove `@Component` it throws "Injection of autowired dependencies failed". Is this what you ment? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're essentially trying to make a pool of `WSD`s?. You're certain that WSD isn't thread-safe?

You can safely throw your queue in the garbage, and use a correct ready made version of [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) instead. It might not necessarily solve your actual problem, but it'll be a working version of what you're attempting here.

Comment: Hi, yes I am trying to make a pool. I want to have only 2 or 3 instances (due to memory) so when request comes and there is a available instance, it will do its work and release the instance. I have no idea whether WSD is thread-safe. This is really a first time I am working with threads and quese so I don't know how to approach to this problem. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: First find out whether WSD is thread-safe or not. If it is, a single instance can be shared by all threads. If not, have a look at BlockingQueue (it's essentially what you were attempting to do with your code).

Comment: You're just assuming that. In any case, I already gave you the alternative.

Comment: I am sure it is not Thread Safe. Yes I will look at it. Thanks.

Comment: No offense, but you said "This is the first time I am making a queue and working with threads". Unless something explicitly says "this is (not) thread-safe", I don't think you would be able to evaluate thread-safeness?

Comment: ok. This is what I think. I have an object WSD. This object has several local variables. During initialization all dictionaries are loaded and around half of those variables is set. When the request comes, it takes an instance and starts analysing text. During this analysation the rest of variables is set. As I am assuming when 2 requests come in the same time and they are using one object, then they are effecting each other.

Comment: Yes shared/modified `instance` variables would make it un-threadsafe. Local variables would be fine (and any variables that wouldn't change after initialization).